# azure-functions-cli: func init spits error "No such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, azure, mono, ubuntu-14.04, azure-functions

I installed 7.x NoodeJs using the folowing URl,
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Installed azure-functions-cli as explained at the link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/12/01/running-azure-functions-locally-with-the-cli/,

```
npm i -g azure-functions-cli
```

Now, when I run "func init", I get the following error,
    $ func init
    : No such file or directory

I then tried to run it the following way and still get the error,

```
$ node /usr/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-cli/lib/main.js init
events.js:161
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn mono /usr/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-cli/bin/func.exe ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1023:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:533:3
```

I also tried to install Mono and rerun the command and that too didn't help. I used the instructions at the following URL for installing Mono,
Install Mono,
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Functions CLI does not work on platforms other than Windows. I'm not sure why you were getting such a poor error message, however.

There is an experimental port of the CLI to run on Mono, but you would need to build the project yourself. Also, it does not support JavaScript functions. The code lives at https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/tree/mono-support.

Comment: @Subhransu If my post was helpful, please accept it as the answer.